# Is it possible to successfully extract an archive file if the download is not complete

Tags: archiving, extract, iso-image

I'm downloading visual studio 2010 professional through MSDN Academic Alliance. And I get the download is finished confirmation even before the progress of the download doesn't reach 100%.
I extracted the iso file and it didn't have any problems or errors extracting its contents. But I noticed some sub folders are empty.
Is it possible that I haven't really downloaded the full content of the archive?

Comment: Do you have display hidden files and folders enabled?

There is a chance that there is stuff in those folders, but it's hidden from view...

Comment: I already enabled the option to show files with hidden file attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is very possible with many archive formats to have missing data when extracting an incomplete download.

What archive format is the download you're using in?

Comment: .img, then I tried changing the file extension to .iso. And I only found a BIG single textfile on it.